# Moving this IK bone just a little causes the leg to twist up

Tags: rigging

After a lot of fiddling, I got the first of 6 mechanical legs, each with several joints and ending in wheels, working the way I wanted. I thought it had been so hard because of some simple oversights. Now I'm not so sure.

After copying the setup for the first leg to the second leg, even a slight movement of the IK bone causes it to twist like a dead spider leg. The axes of rotation of the joints are limited through the IK section of their bone properties. The first leg doesn't have a range set on the axis each joint is free to move in, but it still works very well. I can even tweak the joints individually so the bend is distributed over the joints the way I want. I don't understand why the other one is so different. I have looked for something different and don't see anything.

What is making this go so wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first leg IK chain is somehow linked to the others. The bones were copied to create the other legs, but I didn't think any relationships were preserved when that was done. I don't see any parent relationships that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will solve all your problems but I guess you need to:

- Deparent the second leg controller.
- Move up a bit the central limbs so that it knows how to bend the legs.

Please tell me if it's enough to fix your problem.

[image]

Comment: It cleared up a lot of it. I'm sorry i didn't catch that before posting, i thought i had gone over all the setup to make sure it was the same. I did have hinting for the flexing before but got rid of it when i tried using limits on rotation through properties instead. Thanks for your help, i'll try to finish up. So far trying to put back the hinting hasn't helped but maybe i haven't found the right way.